# validate json array schema

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

guys i have this json

```js
var menu = [{
 name: 'Computers',
 children: [{
  name: 'Notebook'
  children: [{
   name: 'Apple'
  }, {
   name: 'Windows'
  }]
 }, {
  name: Tablets
  children: [{
   name: 'Apple'
  }, {
   name: 'Android'
  }, {
   name: 'Windows'
  }]
 }]
}, {
 name: 'Phones',
 children: [{
  name: 'Android'
  children: [{
   name: 'Samsung'
  }, {
   name: 'Nokia'
  }, {
   name: 'Lenovo'
  }]
 }, {
  name: 'Windows Phones'
  children: [{
   name: 'Microsoft'
  }, {
   name: 'Nokia'
  }]
 }]
}, {
 name: 'Cameras',
 children: [{
  name: 'Digital'
  children: [{
   name: 'Nikon'
  }, {
   name: 'Fuji'
  }]
 }, {
  name: 'DSLR'
  children: [{
   name: 'Canon'
  }, {
   name: 'Nikon'
  }]
 }]
}];
```

it says it is not valid json ... so how to make it valid json ??
any help would be appreciated ... thanks a lot 
btw i am beginner so please help me

any suggestions ?? thanks again :)

Comment: online json validator https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: that's not JSON - that's a plain ol' vanilla javascript object, with syntax errors. what is telling you that's not valid JSON

Comment: Remove parent square bracket [] .i.e., after menu=, double quote for variables names

Comment: @HinaKhuman - WHY!!! that's just completely irrational

Comment: try my answers @hanaa hanaa

Comment: What is telling you this isn't valid JSON? this has nothing to do with JSON - unless this is the content of a file you are trying to load, specifying a json data type ... then it's got more problems than just the missing commas and quotes around one value ...

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing commas, where noted and a suposed to be a string without delimiters in your [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) literal.

```js
var menu = [{
    name: 'Computers',
    children: [{
        name: 'Notebook', // missing ,
        children: [{
            name: 'Apple'
        }, {
            name: 'Windows'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Tablets', // missing string delimiter and comma
        children: [{
            name: 'Apple'
        }, {
            name: 'Android'
        }, {
            name: 'Windows'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Phones',
    children: [{
        name: 'Android', // missing ,
        children: [{
            name: 'Samsung'
        }, {
            name: 'Nokia'
        }, {
            name: 'Lenovo'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Windows Phones', // missing ,
        children: [{
            name: 'Microsoft'
        }, {
            name: 'Nokia'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Cameras',
    children: [{
        name: 'Digital', // missing ,
        children: [{
            name: 'Nikon'
        }, {
            name: 'Fuji'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'DSLR', // missing ,
        children: [{
            name: 'Canon'
        }, {
            name: 'Nikon'
        }]
    }]
}];

console.log(menu);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

- After name property values, `comma` is missing (at various places)
- `Tablets` is not in quotes

Correct syntax would be.

```
var menu = [{
    name: 'Computers',
    children: [{
        name: 'Notebook',
        children: [{
            name: 'Apple'
        }, {
            name: 'Windows'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Tablets',
        children: [{
            name: 'Apple'
        }, {
            name: 'Android'
        }, {
            name: 'Windows'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Phones',
    children: [{
        name: 'Android',
        children: [{
            name: 'Samsung'
        }, {
            name: 'Nokia'
        }, {
            name: 'Lenovo'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Windows Phones',
        children: [{
            name: 'Microsoft'
        }, {
            name: 'Nokia'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Cameras',
    children: [{
        name: 'Digital',
        children: [{
            name: 'Nikon'
        }, {
            name: 'Fuji'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'DSLR',
        children: [{
            name: 'Canon'
        }, {
            name: 'Nikon'
        }]
    }]

}];
```

You can copy your code is chrome's console to see where the error is.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, realized the moment I submitted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put double quotes on key an value like this "key" : "value"

```
 [{
    "name": "Computers",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Notebook",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Apple"
        }, {
            "name": "Windows"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Tablets",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Apple"
        }, {
            "name": "Android"
        }, {
            "name": "Windows"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

And after name property values, comma is missing (at various places)

Comment: the fact that the code starts with `var menu =` should tell you two things. One, **this isn't JSON**, and two, he's not getting an invalid JSON error, because ... well, see point One

Answer (score 0):

key and value should be wrapped  by double quotes

copy paste the code validate here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
     [  
       {  
          "name":"Computers",
          "children":[  
             {  
                "name":"Notebook",
                "children":[  
                   {  
                      "name":"Apple"
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"Windows"
                   }
                ]
             },
             {  
                "name":"Tablets",
                "children":[  
                   {  
                      "name":"Apple"
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"Android"
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"Windows"
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "name":"Phones",
          "children":[  
             {  
                "name":"Android",
                "children":[  
                   {  
                      "name":"Samsung"
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"Nokia"
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"Lenovo"
                   }
                ]
             },
             {  
                "name":"Windows Phones",
                "children":[  
                   {  
                      "name":"Microsoft"
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"Nokia"
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "name":"Cameras",
          "children":[  
             {  
                "name":"Digital",
                "children":[  
                   {  
                      "name":"Nikon"
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"Fuji"
                   }
                ]
             },
             {  
                "name":"DSLR",
                "children":[  
                   {  
                      "name":"Canon"
                   },
                   {  
                      "name":"Nikon"
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```